# Unchecked cast : trying to cast Int or String as T (generic type) in the same method

Tags: kotlin, casting, generic-list, generic-type-argument

I'm pretty new to generic functions (both in java and kotlin). And I use a function that allows me to restore lists (thanks to `SharedPreferences`). These lists are either `MutableList<Int>`, `<String>`, `<Long>`, whatever... Here is the code I'm currently using (I saved the list using `list.toString()`, only if it wasn't empty) :

```
fun <T: Any> restoreList(sharedPrefsKey: String, list: MutableList<T>) {
    savedGame.getString(sharedPrefsKey, null)?.removeSurrounding("[", "]")?.split(", ")?.forEach { list.add((it.toIntOrNull() ?: it) as T) }
}//"it" is already a String, no need to cast in the "if null" ( ?: ) branch
//warning "Unchecked cast: {Comparable<*> & java.io.Serializable} to T" on "as T"
```

So my goal is to know how to cast `String`s safely to T (the type of the elements inside the list passed as argument). Now I get a warning and want to know if what I'm doing is correct or not. Should I also add an `in` modifier? For example : `list: MutableList<in T>` ?

Comment: How this function was supposed to be used? Is it known at the moment of call what (`MutableList<Int>` or `MutableList<String>`) it should return?

Comment: I don't think generics are appropriate here. You need to know if the type is an Int or a String to handle it correctly. You could make the type reified, but since there are only two acceptable types, and they are both handled differently, you should just have two separate functions, one for Ints and one for Strings.

Comment: My goal with this function was to add in a mutableList (`Int` or `String`) the previously saved items (stored as `String`), and that's why I casted the items to T (hoping that this one would be `Int` or `String` respectively). Finally, perhaps write 2 different functions is the best choice. But, if we suppose that the function could be called by lists of any type, how could I convert the String (saved data) into T (type of the elements of the list passed as argument)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [union types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) in Kotlin.
So you can't describe a type `T` to be either `Int` or `String`, hence you can't describe a `MutableList<T>` to be either `MutableList<Int>` or `MutableList<String>`

But when you do `it.toIntOrNull() ?: it` you get even not that, but a mutable list, which may contain `Int` elements as well as a `String` ones (because compiler have no guarantee that this clause will be resolved same way for each element). So compilers tries to infer this type (which should be a most specific common supertype of both `Int` and `String`) and it gets this dreadful `Comparable<*> & java.io.Serializable` type. This impose so serious restrictions on what `T` could be, that it become practically useless (it's like using `MutableList<*>`), and it can't be fixed with variance annotations.

I would suggest using additional functional parameter here, converting `String` (after splitting) into an instance of required type (also note that mutating passed parameter inside a function is a code smell, it's better to be merged with existing mutable list in the same scope it was created):

```kotlin
fun <T> restoreList(sharedPrefsKey: String, converter: (String) -> T): List<T>? =
    savedGame.getString(sharedPrefsKey, null)?.removeSurrounding("[", "]")?.split(", ")?.map { converter(it) }
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val listOfInts = restoreList(sharedPrefKey) { it.toIntOrNull() }
val listOfLongs = restoreList(sharedPrefKey) { it.toLongOrNull() }
val listOfStrings = restoreList(sharedPrefKey) { it }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I wasn't sure if it was possible to pass a converter as an argument in the function. No more warning, just as concise and easier to understand!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do this with reified generics, which are required when you need to inspect the generic type. It will throw an error if you try to call it with a type you don't support in the `when` clause.

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> restoreList(sharedPrefsKey: String, list: MutableList<T>) {
    val strings = savedGame.getString(sharedPrefsKey, null)
            ?.removeSurrounding("[", "]")
            ?.split(", ")
    if (strings == null) {
        Log.w("restoreList", "No preferences found for key $sharedPrefsKey.")
        return
    }
    when (T::class) {
        String::class -> strings.mapTo(list) { it as T }
        Int::class -> strings.mapNotNullTo(list) { it.toIntOrNull() as? T }
        Long::class -> strings.mapNotNullTo(list) { it.toLongOrNull() as? T }
        // And so on for other types.
        else -> error("Unsupported type ${T::class}.")
    }
}
```

Comment: With this code, I can now better understand the generic functions. Unfortunately, this doesn't take away the Unchecked cast warning (even if you use @Suppress) unlike what I would like to do.

Comment: See edit. You can map the Strings to T instead of casting them.